# Compare "argv" and a "int" variable (C)

Tags: c, argv

i'm wondering how can I compare in C language, a number I put on `argv[2]` and a `int` number in my code:

```
EX: prog.exe file.txt 74
========================

int n; 
scanf ("%d", &n);

if (n > argv[2]) 
{ 
   [...] 
}
```

How can I compare those different kind of data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any command line parameters passed to your app are stored in `argv` as character pointers (aka "C strings"). You need to convert the string to an integer via any of the dozens of methods (simplest is [`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/)) before comparing.

If you are writing serious production code, avoid using `atoi` as it is difficult to distinguish between failure and strings evaluating to the number `0`. You should instead use [`strtol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol/) with proper error checking.

Comment: `sscanf(argv[2], "%d", &m)` is also another option.

Comment: Here's a link to some [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/). Yes, I know it's a c++ reference, but it's the same function.

Comment: @TimCooper `scanf` is problematic because the number is coming from argv, but aside from that, just shouldn't ever be used to parse user input due to the risk of buffer overflow

Comment: @jpm: Whoops. Seems I meant `sscanf`.  And aren't buffer overflows only an issue when dealing with strings (`%s`)?

Comment: Unfortunately `atoi` is poorly designed, anyway. `strtol` is a better choice.

Comment: Good point. Plus, `strtol` lets you specify a delimiter of sorts. @TimCooper Probably, but if we keep recommending it for non-string tasks (even if the recommendation comes with a big fat disclaimer), it's going to keep coming to mind when developers need to take string input.

Comment: @jpm, there's no danger of buffer overflow if you use `scanf` to read an integer obviously. The problem with `scanf` is that error checking for inputs like `1234foo` is quite cumbersome.

Comment: @jpm `sscanf` by itself does not cause buffer overflow, it's its imprudent usages that do. If you are careful to specify `%20s` instead of `%s` in your format strings to read data into a 20-character buffer, you'll never see an overrun. The API got a bad rep because it does not force you to supply the limits, but it's not fair to assign all the blame onto the API.

Comment: Yes, but why encourage users to learn an API that will let them shoot themselves in the foot when there is a functionally equivalent API that enforces safety?

Answer (score 3):

Parameters on the command line a character strings. They need to be converted to their respective types. Personally, I would unpack your argv[2] first using an integer variable and atoi; input a user-entered value into `n`, and then compare, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int n;
int argv_2;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int rc = 0;

/* Check for three arguments, program name and two passed. */    

    if(3 == argc) 
    {
        argv_2 = strtol(argv[2], NULL, NULL, 10);

        printf("Please enter a number for the vaue of the variable n\t: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        printf("\n\n");

        if (n > argv_2)
        {
            printf("The value of n: %i is greater than argv[2]: %i\n", 
                   n, argv_2);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("The value of n: %i is not greater than argv[2]: %i\n", 
                   n, argv_2);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Usage: ./test arg1 arg2 \n\n");
    }

    return rc;
}
```

Comment: argv_2 = atoi(argv[2], 10); what "10" stays for? Thank You

Comment: I should have used strtol. I haven't programmed in C for so long, I did not realize atoi had been deprecated. http://www.codecogs.com/reference/computing/c/stdlib.h/atoi.php I edited the answer to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `atoi()` function if you want to convert argv[2] to `int` with including `stdlib.h`
for the `atoi()`. This function simply converts the first number digits of a string until it encounters a non-number member of the string.